# Rave Reports Excel File Render Object?

Tags: delphi, excel, delphi-7, rave-reports

I notice that Rave reports for Delphi 7 (default version) comes with  PDF, HTML, RTF, and TXT Render Objects.  Does anyone know of a place to download a free or opensource render object for Excel, or other file types?

(I am particularly interested in Excel though)

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a last resort (if someone does not respond with a better solution), i will use the text render object to save the file as a .csv file, which can be opened by Excel